# How to use java RMI to forward message ?

Tags: java, rmi

I have the following problem:

I have two clients using an interface and one server running the java rmi implementation of that interface, which is composed by the method msgPass(String host, String msg).
what I want to do is when client A use the Method msgPass(String host,String msg), the rmi server receives that msg and send to the Client B.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either Client B also exposes an interface for the server to consume, or you send it via another way e.g. sockets, web service etc.
I.e. your Client B must act both as client and server

Comment: I did exactly what you say. Thks 4 helping me!